# How can I add double click event and pass the selected row data in Angular KendoUI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I'm having trouble in getting the selected row data in Angular/KendoUI Grid Data. I created a double click event in selecting the row. I did not use the given selectable attribute because I need to select the record from double clicking.

In my component template I did it this way

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" (dblclick)="selectAccount(gridData, $event)">
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some events not available in Kendo Grid because of performance penalties: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/21

You could use the selectChange event from the Kendo Grid component to grab the information or object you need from the grid and then a double click event on the grid. Here is an example of how I handle this:

**On the template**

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="(gridData$ | async)"          
    [selectable]="true"
    (selectionChange)="onSelection($event)"
    (dblclick)="onGridDoubleClick()">
    <kendo-grid-column field="columnA"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="columnB"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**On the .ts component file:**

```
public onSelection(event): void {
    // you will need to declare a selectedItem variable to store this
    this.selectedItem = event.selectedRows[0].dataItem;
}

public onGridDoubleClick(): void { 
    // Do what you need with the selected item 
}
```